# Big O Time Complexity of Nested Loop with recursion

Tags: java, time-complexity

What should be the time complexity of below code snippet

```
void doSomething(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            doSomeOtherStuff(n);
            doSomething(n - 1);
        }
    }
}

void doSomeOtherStuff(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        //did some other stuff
    }
}
```

Is the complexity calculation as: n^2(n + n^2) = O(n^4) is correct? If not please explain

Comment: O(n^4) does seem to be the answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comments to the first answer, I think the complexity of this algorithm is much worse than O(n^4).  @ToddCaywood actually first wrote what I was thinking in my head.  This algorithm is actually something like:

```
O(n^(n^2))
```

an impossibly bad result.  For large datasets, this thing is going to go off into space and never come back.

The way I first looked at this is that each level of recursion adds another set of NESTED `for` loops.  For `n==10`, you have 20 nested for loops.  It just keeps getting deeper and deeper as `n` grows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, O(n^4) is correct.

doSomeOtherStuff(n) is obviously complexity O(n), done n times, also done n times, so the inside portion is O(n^3).

Keeping this in mind, complexity of doSomething(n) [let's call that T(n)] = O(n^3) + T(n-1) where T(n-1) = O(n^3) + T(n-2), etc.  Expanding to (n-1)(O(n^3)) + O(n^3) = n(O(n^3)) = O(n^4).

If you need a formal proof, you can follow the logic above pretty easily, expanded where needed.

Comment: I don't understand why this is only O(n^4).  Don't the number of nested loops go up with `n` due to the recursion?  Isn't it the number of nested loops that determines the `4` in this case?  So since there are more than 4 nested loops, isn't this much worse than O(n^4)?

Comment: If you look at the inside part of the function and expand outward, it's easier to figure out.  So the O(n^3) I think is fairly obvious.  For the recursivO(1) + e portion, look at the definition of each step down, and "add" up at the end.  So for doSomething(n) = O(n^3) + doSomething(n-1) = O(n^3) + O(n^3) + doSomething(n-2), etc.  Going to the end, you have n instances of O(n^3), so multiplying that by another n = O(n^4).  There are MUCH more formal proofs for this, for sure.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  Effectively, the O(n^3) complexity is expanded by n, then n again.... so it's more like O(n^(3*n*n)) = O(n^(n^2))... which is horribly bad.  Good call, Steve.

Comment: Yes!!! - I was just now trying to form a second chance to help you see that.

Comment: Thanks for the chance to make it right ;)  Been a while since I was in algorithm classes haha